# Create a class at run time within a module/namespace

Tags: ruby, class, module, namespaces, runtime

Creating a class **at runtime** is done as follows:

```
klass = Class.new superclass, &block
Object.const_set class_name, klass
```

Example:

```
class Person
  def name
    "Jon"
  end
end

klass = Class.new Person do
  def name
    "#{super} Doe"
  end
end

Object.const_set "Employee", klass

puts Employee.new.name # prints "Jon Doe"
```

Now, let's say that you have a module called Company:

```
module Company
end
```

How do you create the Employee class **at runtime** within the Company module/namespace such that the following yields the same result?

```
puts Company::Employee.new.name # prints "Jon Doe"
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Easier than you think :)

```
Company.const_set "Employee", klass
```

When you set something on `Object`, it becomes global because, well, everything is an `Object`. But you can do `const_set` to every class/module. And remember, modules/classes are just constants. So, `Company::Employee` is a constant `Employee` in a constant `Company`. It's simple :)

Full code:

```
class Person
  def name
    "Jon"
  end
end

klass = Class.new Person do
  def name
    "#{super} Doe"
  end
end

module Company
end

Company.const_set "Employee", klass

Company::Employee.new.name # => "Jon Doe"
```

Comment: Beat you by 2 secs literally :p

Comment: @MichaelKohl: Yes, I spent them on cutting/pasting that line :)

Answer (score 2):

You already had all the necessary pieces:

```
class Person
  def name
    "Jon"
  end
end

klass = Class.new Person do
  def name
    "#{super} Doe"
  end
end

module Company
end

Company.const_set "Employee", klass

puts Company::Employee.new.name # prints "Jon Doe"

Company.constants.grep(/Emp/)
#=> [:Employee]
```